# Converting a Json File to a Map using Gson

Tags: json, dictionary, hashmap, gson, azure-cosmosdb

I currently have the following Json File

```
    [
  {
    "documentId": "138",
    "results": [
      {
        "force_error": true
      },
      {
        "is_duplicate": false
      },
      {
        "is_odd": false
      },
      {
        "is_even": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "documentId": "176",
    "results": [
      {
        "force_error": true
      },
      {
        "is_duplicate": false
      },
      {
        "is_odd": false
      },
      {
        "is_even": true
      }
    ]
  },...etc.
```

I am trying to take this file and make a map or hashmap of it (I later plan to compare it to a document on cosmodb). How can I turn this Json into an object using Gson? Thanks for the help!

---

Updated by @Jay Gong.

Sorry for updating your question directly since it can't be clear in the comment.

You have data like below:

```
  {
    "documentId": "138",
    "results": [
      {
        "force_error": true
      },
      {
        "is_duplicate": false
      },
      {
        "is_odd": false
      },
      {
        "is_even": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then you have other documents against it.

```
"is_odd": {
    "values": [{
        "source": "internal",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "value": false
    }]
}, 
"is_even": {
    "values": [{
        "source": "internal",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "value": true
    }]
}
```

Afterwards,you want to merge it by match-up properties.

```
{
        "documentId": "138",
        "results": [
          {
            "force_error": true
          },
          {
            "is_duplicate": false
          },
          "is_odd": {
            "values": [{
              "source": "internal",
              "locale": "en-US",
              "value": false
          }]
          }, 
          "is_even": {
            "values": [{
              "source": "internal",
              "locale": "en-US",
              "value": true
          }]
       }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Finally, you just want to convert this file into cosmos db distributed documents?

Comment: Afterwards I went to store the results in a json file

Comment: What type `object` do you need? Is it a `Map`? Or `POJO`? Do you have any example how do you want to store it?

Comment: "is_odd": {
        "values": [
          {
            "source": "internal",
            "locale": "en-US",
            "value": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "is_even": {
        "values": [
          {
            "source": "internal",
            "locale": "en-US",
            "value": true
          }
        ]
      }



I want to grab the data, append values like this to it, and then merge it with data from cosmosdb.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `cosmosdb`. Could you show your code how do you want to merge these two different `JSON` models? Do you have any `Java` class model which you want to merge and store in `cosmosdb`? Could you provide some context to your question? Right now it is not clear enough.

Comment: @mshah49rs Tried to update in your answer,any additional requirements you have?

Answer (score 0):

create two maps and add them

This is my proposal margeJson method and test :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class MargeJsonTest {

    String json1 = "{\"documentId\":\"138\",\"results\":[{\"force_error\":true},{\"is_duplicate\":false},{\"is_odd\":false},{\"is_even\":true}]}";
    String json2 = "{\"is_odd\":{\"values\":[{\"source\":\"internal\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"value\":false}]},\"is_even\":{\"values\":[{\"source\":\"internal\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"value\":true}]}}";

    @Test
    public void get() {
        //given
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //when
        Map<String, Object> margeJson = margeJson(gson, json1, json2);
        //then
        assertTrue(margeJson.containsKey("documentId"));
        assertTrue(margeJson.get("documentId").equals("138"));
        assertTrue(margeJson.containsKey("results"));
        assertTrue(margeJson.containsKey("is_odd"));
        assertTrue(margeJson.containsKey("is_even"));

        //back to String JSON conversion
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(
                margeJson)); // {"is_even":{"values":[{"source":"internal","locale":"en-US","value":true}]},"documentId":"138","is_odd":{"values":[{"source":"internal","locale":"en-US","value":false}]},"results":[{"force_error":true},{"is_duplicate":false},{"is_odd":false},{"is_even":true}]}

    }

    private Map<String, Object> margeJson(Gson gson, String json1, String json2) {

        Map map1 = gson.fromJson(json1, HashMap.class);
        Map map2 = gson.fromJson(json2, HashMap.class);

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.putAll(map1);
        map.putAll(map2);

        return map;

    }

}
```